# Enforce maximum size for boost ASIO queue

Tags: c++, queue, boost-asio

Many examples I've found online suggest using a queue to manage messages being used by async_write, which in turn use a completion handler i..e, lambda, that discards data once the async_write is complete. For example, the chat server from boost examples: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/chat/chat_server.cpp. The applicable code is the following:

```
  void do_write()
  {
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
        boost::asio::buffer(write_msgs_.front().data(),
          write_msgs_.front().length()),
        [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/)
        {
          if (!ec)
          {
            write_msgs_.pop_front();
            if (!write_msgs_.empty())
            {
              do_write();
            }
          }
          else
          {
            room_.leave(shared_from_this());
          }
        });
  }
```

However, in the application I'm using it for, it's possible that messages are pushed into write_msgs_ faster than the async_write can complete and thus the queue grows arbitrarily large in memory until the application crashes.

I tried using a thread safe queue that pops messages off of the front if the queue reaches a certain size. The problem is that the completion handler is the only one that gets to decide when data is finished being used, thus my approach failed since it would pop messages off before they are done being used.

Can anyone provide a push in the right direction? Could I use two queues to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a bounded queue, and you need to handle somehow the case of the queue being full.

If you do not need thread safety (i.e. if you use a strand)   you can consider `boost::circular_buffer`.

Otherwise, there is `boost::sync_bounded_queue` in [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/thread/sds.html#thread.sds.synchronized_queues.ref.sync_bounded_queue_ref).

Comment: I feel the data structure I use isn't the main problem. It's the algorithms associated with discarding data. The data being used by the async_write "write_msgs_.front().data()", needs to live somewhere else. It just needs to remain in scope until the completion handler is called:

"Although the buffers object may be copied as necessary, ownership of the underlying memory blocks is retained by the caller, which must guarantee that they remain valid until the handler is called."

Comment: @BrockHargreaves `needs to live somewhere else.` That can be either another queue (which does not help), or the stack of the function that queue the `async_write`. In the second case you need to block (for instance using a future). 
Think about it in another way: if the producer if faster than the consumer (the `async_write`), there is no possible solution, so either we throw away some data, or we make the producer wait for the consumer.